# Powering a Pi 4 with a small power bank

Tags: pi-4, power, power-supply, battery

For my project SamplerBox, I had done many extensive tests in the past and **it was possible to successfully power a RPi 2 for multiple hours** with such a [small 2600mAh power bank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv9N4.png) (18650-battery inside), and even 7 hours with a better-quality battery (see [my article](https://www.samplerbox.org/article/howtopowerrpiwith18650) here).

Of course, it was using a read-only filesystem for which a power failure was not a problem. (Along the multiple hundreds hours of usage, there was not a single SD card failure).

Question: I tried the same with a RPi 4 and it does not seem to work. I know that the RPi4 consumption is higher than RPi2, but is there a way to make it run on lower CPU speed / lower power requirement? More generally, is there a way to make a Rpi4 work with such common small power banks?

---

Note: I would like to avoid dedicated "powerbank RPi Hats" which are more expensive (and by the way, I already use the GPIO / Hat for something other else).

Comment: *"is there a way to make a Rpi4 work with such common small power banks"* -> It's purely a YMMV scenario.  Some banks may work for some things some of the time but this actually is not what they are for (see my answer to the duplicate).  I too have had them work for older models doing low load activities but the upshot is again, that this is a purpose they are **not** designed for, and if you are avoiding other choices because they are slightly "more expensive" -- you get what you pay for and YMMV, or try the right tools for the right job, etc.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks for your comment. Do you have a link (maybe another duplicate?) for this part of the question *"is there a way to make a Rpi4 run on lower CPU speed / lower power requirement?"*? (This part of the question is still interesting on its own I think, and less YMMV)

Comment: Well, it's a valid question all by itself, and really the best questions (most useful to posterity) are exactly that, a simple practical question without a lot of contextual clutter ("because I need to do ____, and related to that is the question of ___" <- Ends up as too localized, harder to find, etc.).

Comment: ...There are [various questions here already related to *underclocking*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=underclock+is%3Aquestion) but they all look to have the problem just mentioned, and AFAICT there's two canonical approaches, via core frequency settings in `/boot/config.txt` and by setting the cpu governor used by the kernel (search around for "cpu governor" and you'll find explanations of that).